# Excel - Toggle Buttons Turn Into Pictures

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I posted this question last spring, and I see another user had a similar issue in 2020. I just can't seem to find a resolution.

---

I have a spreadsheet with Toggle Buttons that points to some basic VBA code that will hide or show specific columns - click the button, columns are automatically hidden for the user. Click the button again, the columns re-appear.

A couple of users over the last few years have the buttons mysteriously turn into an picture. When they click on the button, the PICTURE TOOLS tab appears in the ribbon. This happens to maybe 3 of our 20ish users, but is consistent every month.

To fix it, I just delete and replace the Toggle buttons and it works fine when sent back, but at some point in the month something triggers this again.

Has anyone ever experienced a user-error that turns Toggle Buttons into images? Perhaps something with ActiveX? Or conversely - is there something I can do that isn't an ActiveX Control that would have the same function?

Comment: Form Control maybe? In my experience they tend to be less buggy than ActiveX Controls.

Comment: I'm not SUPER familiar with it, as simple as that may be. Would I need to then write a macro instead of have the VBA code?

Comment: that was a dumb question. anyway, I think I got it!! thanks for the suggestion! Crossing my fingers this works long term! :-)

Comment: @BigBen Sheet Form Toggle button control? I never could see such a control between available 'Form controls' ... Is it possible to configure Excel in a way to offer it?

Comment: You can use a shape with an attached macro - if you need a "toggle" behavior then you can reformat the shape after hiding/showing the columns.

Comment: @FaneDuru I did a basic If Statement in the macro to simulate the "toggle" nature.  if the rows are hidden, unhide them. else, hide them.